# .NET7 v4 Azure function failing with "Could not load file or assembly System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a v4 Azure function app targeting net7.0. It has a blob-triggered function that is firing when a new blob is created but failing with the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: PendingAlbumsProcessor. My.Namespace.Function: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The function has a single project reference to another .NET7 project that has a dependency on System.Text.Json 7.0.2. But when I explore the output directory of the function when debugging locally there is no copy of System.Text.Json.dll. This is true even when I explicitly reference the same version of the package in my function app as follows (this is the full set of references I have):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="7.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I saw advice elsewhere to use `_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput` but this makes no difference.

So what gives?

Comment: Is failure on client or server?  Is failure one machine where code was built or another machine? If deploy on different machine than build did you publish and run setup.exe on deploy machine?

Comment: This is running locally. The failure occurs when the function is triggered by a blob file being created.

Comment: The error is occurring when a file is being loaded.  Did you install System.Text.JSON? See : https://www.developer.com/design/introducing-the-new-system-text-json-apis/

Comment: Have you actually read my question?

Comment: Where did you say that you installed (or attempted to install) System.Text.Json?  The version may be wrong.  It older version existing in error it is due to the intermediate obj files not being recompiled.  Do a clean built do force older files to recompile.  The c# compiler dependencies do no check libraries.  So when you update a library you must force the compiler to recompile files.